# JAVA program keeps blocking the terminal for input even when it's not supposed to take input

Tags: java

So I debugged and went to the base of the problem. Basically, I am running a few testcases and

```
 int no_of_test = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
 for(int t = 0;t<no_of_test;t++){//do something}`
```

Works fine. However,

```
for(int t=0;t<Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());t++){//do something}
```

Here, it keeps waiting for input after each iteration.

In python I could do `for t in range(int(input())` and it wouldn't block for input after every iteration, why is that not the case in JAVA? What am I missing?

Comment: This is a classic `for` loop, the condition is executed on each iteration. That is just how `for` loops work in java.

Comment: the condition (second argument) in the *for* cycle is evaluated after each iteration, so you need to use the first code

Comment: And the lesson here is that Java is not Python. The way to do something in Python is not necessarily the way to do it in Java.

Comment: The equivalent in Java would be : `IntStream.range(1, in.readLine()).forEach(i -> { /* do something */});`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With

```
for(int t=0;t<Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());t++){//do something}
```

The `Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())` piece is re-evaluated every iteration.

Whereas with

```
int no_of_test = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
for(int t = 0;t<no_of_test;t++){//do something}
```

The `Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())` is evaluated once only.

Answer (score 1):

It keeps waiting because second statement is a condition which is checked before each iteration.

```
for(int t=0; t<Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); t++)
```

- Statement 1: sets a variable before the loop starts (int t = 0).
- Statement 2: defines the condition for the loop to run. If the condition is true, the loop will start over again, if it is false, the loop will end.
- Statement 3: increases a value (t++) each time the code block in the loop has been executed.

The only case when a loop can end is when you don't give a input which will keep waiting for long till you enter one, so it's a never ending loop.

If you still want to end the loop, input something which is not a number.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are different code constructions.

In the Python sample `range()` is function. It's called once and returns integer sequence as a result. So, loop iterates over the sequence of values.

In the Java sample `t < Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())` is the loop condition and it must be checked for every iteration. Java analog to your python code can be:

```
IntStream.range(0, Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())).forEach((e) -> {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In first case you are doing `in.read()` outside the loop
In second case, you got `in.read()` inside loop execution.

Remember that loop condition is evaluated on every iteration, so you are doinb `in.read` on every iteration.

Maybe you wanted to do this

```
for(int t=0,tests=<Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());t<tests;t++) {body}
```

?

Comment: actually I wanted to avoid typing out another variable (time constraints), seems like that's not possible in JAVA.

Comment: Where is it then?

Comment: solved, others suggested to use stream to achieve the same functionality in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

> ```
> BasicForStatement:
>     for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement
>
> ForStatementNoShortIf:
>      for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) StatementNoShortIf
>
> ForInit:
>      StatementExpressionList
>      LocalVariableDeclaration
>
> ForUpdate:
>     StatementExpressionList
>
> StatementExpressionList:
>     StatementExpression
>     StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
> ```
>
> 14.14.1.2. Iteration of for Statement
>
> Next, a for iteration step is performed, as follows:
>
> If the Expression is present, it is evaluated. If the result is of
>   type Boolean, it is subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

In other words, `t < Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())` is executed once per each iteration of the loop.

It is explained better in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

> The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of
>   values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the
>   way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is
>   satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>     statement(s) }
> ```
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> - **The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop**; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or
>     decrement a value.

If you want something similar to `for t in range(int(input())`, you can use the Streams API:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import static java.lang.System.console;

// option 1
try (final BufferedReader console = new 
           BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
  IntStream.range(0, parseInt(console.readLine())).forEach(i -> {
    System.out.println(i);
  });
}

// option 2 (fails in some IDEs as console() will return null)
IntStream.range(0, parseInt(console().readLine())).forEach(i -> {
  System.out.println(i);
});
```